# How to resolve 'TypeError: http.IncomingMessage is undefined'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

Using Heroku, I am trying to publish my Node.js server. However, I am getting the below error I can not google

> TypeError: http.IncomingMessage is undefined

[Image of error/ Broken Heroku Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBM86.png)

Here is my App.js

```
var express = require('express'); // Express web server framework
var request = require('request'); // "Request" library
var querystring = require('querystring');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

var client_id = 'e2597350284b4ff3a3d8c0f4b1554ec6'; // Your client id
var client_secret = 'deb0ca85d1fd461ca486cd251ff29870'; // Your secret
var redirect_uri = 'https://lookatmyspotify.herokuapp.com/callback'; // Or Your redirect uri

/**
 * Generates a random string containing numbers and letters
 * @param  {number} length The length of the string
 * @return {string} The generated string
 */
var generateRandomString = function(length) {
  var text = '';
  var possible = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  }
  return text;
};

var stateKey = 'spotify_auth_state';

var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
   .use(cookieParser());

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {

  var state = generateRandomString(16);
  res.cookie(stateKey, state);

  // your application requests authorization
  var scope = 'user-read-private user-read-email user-read-playback-state playlist-read-private playlist-read-collaborative user-library-read user-read-private user-read-recently-played user-read-currently-playing';
  res.redirect('https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?' +
    querystring.stringify({
      response_type: 'code',
      client_id: client_id,
      scope: scope,
      redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
      state: state
    }));
});

app.get('/callback', function(req, res) {

  // your application requests refresh and access tokens
  // after checking the state parameter

  var code = req.query.code || null;
  var state = req.query.state || null;
  var storedState = req.cookies ? req.cookies[stateKey] : null;

  if (state === null || state !== storedState) {
    res.redirect('/#' +
      querystring.stringify({
        error: 'state_mismatch'
      }));
  } else {
    res.clearCookie(stateKey);
    var authOptions = {
      url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
      form: {
        code: code,
        redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
        grant_type: 'authorization_code'
      },
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (new Buffer(client_id + ':' + client_secret).toString('base64'))
      },
      json: true
    };

    request.post(authOptions, function(error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {

        var access_token = body.access_token,
            refresh_token = body.refresh_token;

        var options = {
          url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me',
          headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token },
          json: true
        };

        // use the access token to access the Spotify Web API
        request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
          console.log(body);
        });

        // we can also pass the token to the browser to make requests from there
        res.redirect('https://lookatmyspotify.herokuapp.com/#' +
          querystring.stringify({
            access_token: access_token,
            refresh_token: refresh_token
          }));
      } else {
        res.redirect('/#' +
          querystring.stringify({
            error: 'invalid_token'
          }));
      }
    });
  }
});

app.get('/refresh_token', function(req, res) {

  // requesting access token from refresh token
  var refresh_token = req.query.refresh_token;
  var authOptions = {
    url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (new Buffer(client_id + ':' + client_secret).toString('base64')) },
    form: {
      grant_type: 'refresh_token',
      refresh_token: refresh_token
    },
    json: true
  };

  request.post(authOptions, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      var access_token = body.access_token;
      res.send({
        'access_token': access_token
      });
    }
  });
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('index.html');
});


console.log('Listening on https://lookatmyspotify.herokuapp.com');
app.listen(process.env.PORT);



// WEBPACK FOOTER //
// src/App.js

      request.post(authOptions, function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
          var access_token = body.access_token;
          res.send({
            'access_token': access_token
          });
        }
      });
    });

    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
            res.sendFile('index.html');
    });

    console.log('Listening on 8888');
    app.listen(8888);
```

Upon pasting that, I realised that the `app.listen(8888)` was used when hosting locally but it does not exist in my actual app.js I am uploaded. Where is this random footer coming from and why can I not find it if I copy and paste?

How can I fix the ***TypeError: http.IncomingMessage is undefined***?

Comment: Found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the issue but it looks like there's an extra "`});`" in this code block at the bottom of your App.js:

```
  request.post(authOptions, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      var access_token = body.access_token;
      res.send({
        'access_token': access_token
      });
    }
  });
});
```